# Json utility сериализует ли словарь или лучше списками?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Мне нужно иметь названия объекта и некое кол-во информации о нем в виде числа, нужно это делать с помощью словаря, т.е. брать по ключу его названия и по значению это число, или лучше двумя списками где схема та же, но нужно будет реализовать несложный поиск.

Что выбрать, словарь (не знаю сериализуеться ли он с помощью JsonUtility) или списки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, не сериализует.

У Unity есть интерфейс [ISerializationCallbackReceiver](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ISerializationCallbackReceiver.html). В нём два метода, которые вызываются до и после сериализации. Можете продолжать использовать словарь, но до сериализации превращать его в два списка, а после эти cписки превращать в словарь.

Если объектов не много, можете и просто иметь один лист и через метод [Find(Predicate predicate)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=netframework-4.7.2) искать нужный вам элемент

Comment: Справедливости ради, в первой ссылке лежит пример сериализации/десериализации словаря. Хороший ответ.

Comment: Так на выходе всеравно же нужно ссылаться на этот объект, я не могу прям в scriptable object его менять

Comment: @k0vpack, в каком плане не можете? Там по первой ссылке прямо код того, как можно сериализовать словарь

Comment: @M.Green ну это не совсем том, у меня не появляються поля для записи, у меня там ожидаеться скрипт SerializationCallbackScript

Comment: @k0vpack, код класса большой? Если приложите его к вопросу, возможно, смогу помочь) а то не сильно понимаю проблему

Comment: @M.Green какой класса? Мне я просто в скриптейбл обжект пишу названия класса и все.